# Language detection not working in Typo3 6.2.12

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, language-detection

I've a website which has 2 languages: German (de) as default and English (en) as translated. I am trying to implement language detection functionality in the website using the extension "rlmp_language_detection" version 7.0.0.

What I want to achieve is, for the countries Austria (at), Switzerland (ch) and Germany (de), the website should be stay in default language German and for all others, the users in other countries should see the website in English.

I've added the below typoscript to implement this. But not working anymore;

```
plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1 {
    defaultLang = de
    languageAliases >
    languageAliases {
        de = de
        at = de
        ch = de
    }
    countryCodeToLanguageCode >
    countryCodeToLanguageCode {
        de = de
        at = de
        ch = de
    }
}
page.987 =< plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1
```

Can you please help me to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a hint: as probably all subpages will have the language in the URL, try setting the language detection only when no language is given / for the home page. Else your caching / static file caching will suffer, and with it the site's performance

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? Suppose my domain is http://www.example.com/ and for translated version, it is http://www.example.com/en/. I am using this extension first time and I didn't know much more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following configuration;

```
plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1 {
   useOneTreeMethod = 1
   defaultLang = de
   limitToLanguages = de,en
}

page.987 =< plugin.tx_rlmplanguagedetection_pi1
```

I understood that the functionality is not working only with this configuration. We need to "Select Official Language (ISO code):" in the website langauge ( alternate language we added in the root ).

Now its works as intended..:)